# Stacking bootstrap column divs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to stack a bootstrap column so that it has a job title, next line job location, then following job etc. What is the correct way to do this?

fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/d3zcnzdf/

```
<div class="job-content">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <h4 style="float:left">Senior Engineer Manager</h4>
        <br>
            <p style="float:left">Toronto, Taiwan</p>

            <h4 style="float:left"> Senior Community Writer</h4>
              <p style="float:left">Miami</p>
          <h4 style="float:left">Andriod Developer</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: do you want the job title and location in the same line or the next line?

Comment: yeah i want the location next line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `style="float:left"` from `h4` and `p` tags. here is a forked [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8t3bq1uj/)

Comment: Many thanks! Sometimes the answer is easier than expected